# Matlab : If 'A' is an indexed variable, performance can be improved using logical indexing instead of FIND

Tags: matlab

In the title there is the recommendation by MATLAB to optimize my code, but I don't understand how can I optimize this

```
X2 = X(~points_in_Cluster,:); %points non vue
A = (1:length(points_in_Cluster))'.*~points_in_Cluster;
Neighbors2 = find(pdist2(X(j,:),X2) <= epsilon);
A = A(A~=0);
Neighbors2 = A(Neighbors2)';
Neighbors = ([Neighbors Neighbors2]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is unnecessary in your case because you can use an array of `logical` values *directly* to index into an array. There is an extensive article on this in MATLAB's own [online documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)

As a brief example:

```
data = [1, 2, 3];
mask = [true, false, true];

% Using find (slow because it's an extra step)
data(find(mask))
%   1   3

% Using the logical array directly
data(mask)
%   1   3
```

So for your code, it would look something like:

```
Neighbors2 = pdist2(X(j,:),X2) <= epsilon;
A = A(A~=0);
Neighbors2 = A(Neighbors2).';
Neighbors = ([Neighbors Neighbors2]);
```

As a side-note, you'll want to use `.'` if you want the transpose rather than `'`